# Add parallax effect to SKSpriteNode instead of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, parallax, skspritenode

So I need to implement the parallax effect to a SKSpriteNode in my scene. I've done this before in single view apps and using UIImageViews, but now I face the following problem: SKSpriteNodes don't have the property addMotionEffect. I've been searching around and can't seem to find anything similar. The code I use for single view apps:

```
@IBOutlet weak var x: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    applyMotionEffect(toView: x)
}

func applyMotionEffect(toView view:UIView) {
    let xMotion = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", type: .tiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
    xMotion.minimumRelativeValue = -10
    xMotion.maximumRelativeValue = 10

    let yMotion = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.y", type: .tiltAlongVerticalAxis)
    yMotion.minimumRelativeValue = -10
    yMotion.maximumRelativeValue = 10

    let group = UIMotionEffectGroup()
    group.motionEffects = [xMotion, yMotion]

    view.addMotionEffect(group)
}
```

I need to achieve something like this:

```
spriteNode.addMotionEffect(group)
```

Comment: you may want to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32325944/2450755

Comment: I´ll take a look, thanks.